# I have been struggling a lot to find any relevant doc on Azure Synapse Analytics to provision Linked Service for Azure KeyVault using CLI

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-cli, azure-synapse

I have been struggling a lot to find any relevant doc on Azure Synapse Analytics to provision Linked Service for Azure KeyVault using  CLI.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below CLI Cmdlet, to create a Key Vault linked service to the Azure Synapse analytics workspace.

```
az synapse linked-service create --file
                                 --name
                                 --workspace-name
                                 [--no-wait]
                                 [--subscription]
```

Using the above cmdlet, we are able to create a key vault linked service to the Synapse analytics workspace in our local environment.

for `--file` parameter in the above cmdlet, we need to declare the properties of the linked service in a json file.

**Here is the Sample Json that we have used in our local environment:**

```html
{
   "properties":{
      "type":"AzureKeyVault",
      "typeProperties":{
         "baseUrl":"https://xxxx.vault.azure.net/"
      },
      "description":"<Requireddescription>",
      "annotations":[<RequiredAnnotations>],
      "parameters":{      ## Required Parameters 
      }
   }
}
```

**Here is the Sample output for reference:**

[image]

**For more information you refer to the following documentation:**

1. [Az synapse linked-service create cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/synapse/linked-service?view=azure-cli-latest#az-synapse-linked-service-create)
2. About what all the properties that we can pass to [AzurekeyVaultLinkedService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/synapse/data-plane/linked-service/create-or-update-linked-service#azurekeyvaultlinkedservice) & their respective datatypes.

Comment: Could you please put the json contents above. Masking the pii section. Secondly, in case of function, it requests for function secret key. How can that be provided via arm template. Any reference doc for that?

Comment: @VenkateshDodda-MT - there is no need to ask for people to accept your answer. Also: the OP showed no work and no specific issue, and the question was essentially a documentation request (as such, it's off-topic as written).